# Excel - randomly select row based on column criteria, without duplicates/repeats

Tags: vba, excel

I have this list imported from a website (and updated on occasion): the first column (A) has first name, the second column (B) has last name and the third column (c) has company name.

I want to randomly select a row (with first, last and company name) based on a certain company.

And now to the tricky part: the (name, last name) must not be randomly selected next time.

Comment: You can even do that without VBA simply by using the Excel function `RandBetween`. That will give you a single number in a given range. If you set the range from 1 to as many as there are names in your list then you are done. If you have to do it with VBA then you can also call the function from within VBA or use the `Randomize` function instead: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8zedbtdt(v=vs.90).aspx When you are saying that the name should not be random the next time. What do you mean by that? The next name in the list? The first name? The same name? Why do you need VBA for that?

Comment: i think he means that a row should only be selected once... Marc you will Need to track the random numbers in another sheet, i think you will Need vba for it

Comment: What i mean is, the next time I import the list and select a random name. The previously selected name from last time, must not be selected.

Answer (score 0):

We can do this in two steps:

1. gather a list of people for the certain company
2. shuffle the list made in step #1

Say we have 1000 people like:

[image]

In **E1** we place the company name.  Then in **D1** enter:

```
=IF(C1=$E$1,1,"")
```

and in **D2** enter:

```
=IF(C2=$E$1,1+MAX($D$1:D1),"")
```

and copy down.  This will produce a retrieval key for the people.  To count the number of people to retrieve in **E2** enter:

```
=MAX(D:D)
```

To retrieve the people, in **F1** enter:

```
=IF(ROW()>$E$2,"",INDEX(A:A,MATCH(ROWS($1:1),D:D,0))& " " & INDEX(B:B,MATCH(ROWS($1:1),D:D,0)))
```

and copy down.
In step #2 we run a macro to take the people in column **F**, shuffle them, and place the shuffled list in column **G**:

```
Sub createPickList()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long

    N = Range("E2").Value
    ReDim arr(1 To N)
    For i = 1 To N
        arr(i) = Cells(i, "F").Value
    Next i

    Call aSort(arr)

    For i = 1 To N
        Cells(i, "G").Value = arr(i)
    Next i
End Sub
Public Sub aSort(ByRef InOut)

    Dim i As Long, J As Long, Low As Long
    Dim Hi As Long, Temp As Variant

    Low = LBound(InOut)
    Hi = UBound(InOut)

    J = (Hi - Low + 1) \ 2
    Do While J > 0
        For i = Low To Hi - J
          If InOut(i) > InOut(i + J) Then
            Temp = InOut(i)
            InOut(i) = InOut(i + J)
            InOut(i + J) = Temp
          End If
        Next i
        For i = Hi - J To Low Step -1
          If InOut(i) > InOut(i + J) Then
            Temp = InOut(i)
            InOut(i) = InOut(i + J)
            InOut(i + J) = Temp
          End If
        Next i
        J = J \ 2
    Loop
End Sub
```

[image]

Your first pick will be **G1**, the next pick will be **G2**, etc.  All people picked will be GE people and there will be no repeats.